# SQL formatter in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Could anyone suggest any good sql formatter in java. I am currently using org.hibernate.jdbc.util.BasicFormatterImpl. Problem with BasicFormatterImpl is that it moves some keywords to new line so   `group` becomes 
` {newline}group`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BasicFormatterImpl impliments interface org.hibernate.jdbc.util.Formatter

There are only 2 implementations available

> class    BasicFormatterImpl
>             Performs formatting of basic SQL statements (DML + query).
>    class    DDLFormatterImpl
>             Performs formatting of DDL SQL statements.

I do not see any other implementation for this interface therefore you will need to write a custom implementation of your own